# Why does my waveform graph display pulses of width 3 ms when I specify them to be 2 ms in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview, waveform

I am trying to generate pulse waves with a width of 2 milliseconds and frequency of approximately 100 Hz as shown below:

[image]

According to this website: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2991/en#toc1 
under the section "Introduction to Pulse Width Modulation" it describes the duty cycle to be 20% if pulse width is 2 ms with a frequency of 100 Hz (or 10 milliseconds).

As you can see in the diagram above the "duty cycle %" indicator correctly computes a percentage close to 20%.

If I perform the calculations correctly, why am I getting a waveform of pulses that have a width of 3 ms instead of 2 ms shown below?

[image]

Following is the back panel diagram containing the logic I am using to generate the waveform:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generation frequency is 1 kHz, so you are at the minimum resolution.
Your pulse is 2 ms high. I would advise you to make the samplerate higher.

Comment: Technically you were correct.  I needed to increase my sampling rate.  I changed it from 1kHz to 200kHz.  This made my square wave actually look like square wave (finally).  But the square wave still does not look right.

Comment: I added a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755377/why-are-the-pulse-width-and-frequency-of-pulse-not-correct-in-my-labview-wavefor