# Why are the pulse width and frequency of pulse not correct in my labview waveform?

Tags: labview, waveform

In the following image you see I set the pulse frequency to 50 Hz and pulse width to 2ms. 
The duty cycle computes to 10%, which is fed into a signal simulator.

[image]

When I execute the labview program the waveform I get is shown below:

[image]

This waveform is clearly not correct because pulse width and pulse frequency both appear to be about 10ms.

Following is the back panel wiring diagram.

[image]

My sampling rate is set to 200000Hz.

Why are my pulses not showing up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not added the duty cycle to the function generator. So it will use the default duty cycle (50 %).

Comment: Yes you are correct. I must have forgotten to rewire it back when I replaced the square_wave VI with the "simulate signal" one. However, my frequencies are still not correct.  I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776538/why-does-my-waveform-not-have-the-right-frequency-intervals-in-labview#