# Why does my waveform not have the right frequency intervals in labview?

Tags: labview, waveform

In the LabView GUI I set the frequency to 300Hz = 1/300 seconds = 3.333 milliseconds and the pulse width to 2 milliseconds. This computes to a duty cycle of 60%.

[image]

Why are intervals between the pulses shown below not equal to 3.333 milliseconds? They look closer to 1 millisecond,which is way off.

[image]

Following is a wiring diagram I am using:

[image]

Is it possible the problem is my timed loop being set to loop every second? Should I loop faster?  What kind of a loop should I be using?

Comment: Could you show the configration of the Simulate Signal Express VI?

Comment: your first puls rise is at about 0.0002, the fall at about 0.0022 (so 2 ms width) and the second rise at about 0.0036, pretty much 3.3ms between the pulses

Comment: Oh, I see.  I was looking at the difference between a pulse drop and pulse rise.  But I should have been looking at a the difference between pulse rise to pulse rise. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pulse rise every 3.333 ms, so that's fine. You don't need a timed loop, the express VI will maintain phase, just make sure it runs more often than the amount of data the express VI produces. A simple wait ms will do.

Comment: How do I know how long for the wait ms to wait for? Is this something that can be determined?

Comment: It should be in the order of the created data by the express VI. The output waveform contains the number of samples and the sample frequency.