# How do I configure DAQ assistant to generate voltage pulses defined by a waveform?

Tags: labview, oscilloscope, daq-mx

How do I feed the waveform pulses into [DAQ Assistant](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2744/en#toc1) to cause a [DAQ 6259 board](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371022k.pdf) to generate desired voltage pulses?

Using the [Simulate Signal](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvexpress/simulate_signal/) express VI I have created a [square pulse waveform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776538/why-does-my-waveform-not-have-the-right-frequency-intervals-in-labview).

My goal is to allow a LabView user to configure the Frequency and Pulse width using knobs from the [GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776538/why-does-my-waveform-not-have-the-right-frequency-intervals-in-labview) as needed in order to generate a desired pulse train.  This pulse train should be sent to the DAQ 6259 to generate a voltage pulse train.  The voltage pulse train would be captured by an oscilloscope in order to verify its correctness (i.e. the captured pulse train looks exactly like the waveform displayed in the labview GUI).

What is the simplest way this can be achieved? Are there any tutorials that explain how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the example finder (Help>Find Examples...)

Hardware Input and Output > DAQmx> Analog Output / Digital Output

There are a bunch of examples in there that will get you 90% of the way